# Position:fixed not working in Safari

Tags: css, safari

Essentially I have a bar which needs to be fixed to the bottom of the page. It works fine with Chrome, Firefox and IE, but in Safari the bar scrolls with the page. The css I'm using is:

```css
.footer-bar {
  bottom:0;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  z-index:10;
}
```

I'm really not sure why it's not working. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Consider assigning an `height` property.

http://jsfiddle.net/ymbrafda/

```
.footer-bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height: 100px;
  z-index:10;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Please consider creating a js fiddle or posting all your html and css code thanks!